# Connecting a Dell Optiplex 755 to 4 monitors

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dvi, dell-optiplex

A few months ago I connected 4 (four) Dell 2009W monitors to a Dell OptiPlex 790 01. The OS was Windows 7 Enterprise (x64) Service Pack 1 (build 7601)

I used the original Dell proprietary connection type DMS059 to dual DVI to connect two of the monitors.  I then installed a second graphics card mdoel Radeon HD 5450 and attached a DVI splitter to the other 2 monitors.  This setup worked successfully.

Two weeks ago I dismantled the setup and moved it across the room and hooked them back up. Now, I can only connect to 2 of the monitors successfully.  When I attempt to extend the desktop to the other 2 monitors they do not show up as a choice.

I have removed the display card and re-booted the computer with just one card installed. I still am able to view with 2 monitors.
When I re-install the display card and attempt to extend the desktop to these other 2 monitors i receive the same results.

Q: Why does it not work now?

It is the same setup as before when all 4 monitors worked successfully?

Comment: Does the 2nd graphics card show up in device manager ?

Comment: I'd probably start my troubleshooting at the bios - see whether there's any option to have both cards active. On the last 3-4 generations of intel systems it should be something like 'igpu multi monitor'

Comment: what are drivers? make sure the cards are using the correct drivers, they might be using microsoft standard drivers instead of specific card drivers. I have also had to setup one card first,

Comment: Note that the "splitter" is not proprietary to Dell. It's [DMS-59](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59), which is a common standard for space-saving dual monitor plugs.